# What's the alphabetical counterpart of the word "digit"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, terminology, semantics, technical

---

Characters:

Numbers = 0123456789
Letters = ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

---

Characters:

Digits = 0123456789
_________ = ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

---

Characters:

Numerical = 0123456789
Alphabetical = ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

---

Comment: Strictly speaking, 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. is a [*sequence of numbers*](https://mathigon.org/world/Sequences), and  each number in the sequence is called a *term*. Random *numbers* would be, e.g. 10, 21, 2, 190 etc.

Comment: I believe your premise is flawed, I did a bit of research and found this explanation "A digit is a single symbol used to make numerals. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9 are the ten digits we use in everyday numerals. Example: The numeral 153 is made up of 3 digits ("1", "5" and "3"). Example: The numeral 46 is made up of 2 digits ("4", and "6")." https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/numbers-numerals-digits.html

Comment: @Mari-Lou OP is mixing definitions for 'numbers' in a confusing way.

Comment: A ***digit*** is any one of the ten numbers 0 to 9, and its equivalent in the alphabet of a language is ***letter***.

Comment: The counterpart to numbers should be words

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks for the thoughtful comments. You might be right. I originally wrote *integers* instead of *numbers*. But it probably wouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what you meant to ask, but the answer to the question you actually asked is:

**letter**

A number is composed of many digits. A word is composed of many letters.

The word 'letter' fits exactly into the blank of your second box, because that makes it identical to the first box.

You can say "The digits in 123 are 1, 2 and 3. The letters in CAT are C, A and T".

You can also say "The digits in the base 10 numeric system are 0123456789", and correspondingly "The letters in the English Alphabet are ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".

Letter pretty much fits everywhere when talking about words or alphabets in the places you would write 'digit' when talking about numbers.

Answer (score 1):

> A letter is a **grapheme** (written character) in an alphabetic system of writing.
>
> It is a visual representation of the smallest unit of spoken sound. Letters broadly correspond to phonemes in the spoken form of the language, although there is rarely a consistent, exact correspondence between letters and phonemes.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_(alphabet))

> **Grapheme** : The class of letters and other visual symbols that represent a phoneme or cluster of phonemes, as e.g. the grapheme 〈f〉 consists of the allographs (see allograph n.2) f, ff, F, Ff, gh, ph, and Ph which represent the phoneme /f/ in fun, huffy, Fingal, Ffoulkes, cough, graph, and Philip respectively; so, in a given writing system of a given language, a feature of written expression that cannot be analysed into smaller meaningful units.

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/80826?redirectedFrom=grapheme#eid)

Comment: Thanks for the solid contribution. You were on the right track re: the kind of lexicon I had in mind. It just doesn't quite fit.